# C# REST dictionary DTO

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, dto

What is the best way to design a DTO for a REST API to get a resource that is semantically a dictionary?

Example: Get the number of employees by age -> should return a set of couples (age, number) of type (int, int).

An easy way should be an array of structures, like:

```
[
    {
      age: 30,
      number: 3
    },
    {
      age: 31,
      number: 4
    },
    {
      age: 32,
      number: 5
    }
]
```

but this does not enforces that the key should be unique.
Semantically, I'd rather prefer a dictionary, like:

```
{
    "30": 3,
    "31": 4,
    "32": 5
}
```

Is there a way to define such a DTO in C#, so that it can be easily serialized/deserialized?

Answer (score 4):

Your second `Json` is not valid, it should look like:

```
{
    "30": 3,
    "31": 4,
    "32": 5
}
```

And in `c#` it's just a `Dictionary<string, int>`

You could easiliy deserialize/serialize it with [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/)

```
var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(text);

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
             new Dictionary<string, int> { { "1", 2 }, {"3",4}});
```

Comment: No need to perform a conversion of the keys to string: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42982286/1288109

Comment: @Starnutoditopo  You do have string keys  in your sample, sure it could be int-int dictioniary, but in your json you have string keys and int values

Comment: That's Json syntax: you cannot have unquoted numeral keys! Numeral keys MUST be quoted! Look at a json specifications! Anyway, also  Json.Net serializes it with quotes: try the example suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42982286/1288109 to believe

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [maksim-simkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5281555/maksim-simkin) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42979543/1288109), dictionaries are natively supported by [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/).

Here's an example:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, int>>(text);

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<int, int> { { 30, 3 }, { 31, 4}});

// here serialized == "{\"30\":3,\"31\":4,\"32\":5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can be useful, this serialization is supported in [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) through the DynamicDictionary class (in namespace Nancy). In a NancyModule, you can create a model like this:

```
        DynamicDictionary dynamicDictionary = ToDynamicDictionary(dictionary);
        return this
          .Negotiate
          .WithModel(dynamicDictionary)
          .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Then, you have to convert your keys to a string, using this helper method:

```
private static DynamicDictionary ToDynamicDictionary(IDictionary<int, int> dictionary)
    {
        DynamicDictionary result = new DynamicDictionary();
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            result.Add(pair.Key.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), pair.Value);
        }

        return result;
    }
```